# Laravel: Generating and downloading a CSV file using StreamedResponse produces ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE

Tags: php, laravel, symfony

I have a controller method like so:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse;

public function downloadTransactions($type)
{
    $this->authorize('download', Invoice::class);

    $filename = 'invoices-' . strtolower($type) . '.csv';

    $response = new StreamedResponse(function() {

        Invoice::generateTransactionsCsv($type);

    }, 200, [
        'Content-Type' => 'text/csv',
        'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"',
    ]);

    return $response;

}
```

and then in my `Invoice` model I am populating the file:

```
public static function generateTransactionsCsv($type = null)
{
    // Open output stream
    $handle = fopen('php://output', 'w');

    // Add CSV headers
    fputcsv($handle, [
        'ID',
        'REF',
        'DESCRIPTION',
        'DATE',
        'AMOUNT',
    ]);

    // Close the output stream
    fclose($handle);
}
```

but I get an `ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE` in Chrome, although I would assume the browser doesn't matter. I've checked similar questions which suggest installing the `zip` extension but I already have it installed. Using PHP 7.1 locally. Also tried looking at the logs but there doesn't seem to be anything there (using Valet locally).

If I move the logic from the model to the controller then it works fine but my example above is simplified to just the header row of the csv, in reality, there's a bit more to it so I'd like to keep the logic in the model if possible.

I've also tried opening and closing the file handle in the controller and passing it the model but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it was because the `$type` variable wasn't being passed correctly:

```
$response = new StreamedResponse(function() use ($type) {
    ....
}
```

Was able to figure it out thanks to Safari, it downloaded a csv with the Laravel error trace in it which was weird, I didn't think it would be any different from Chrome.